# Hosting Angular frontend with node backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Angular front-end application supported by a NodeJS backend server. I use Mysql as my database. I am thinking of using Amazon Beanstalk for my NodeJS application, but can I host my Angular application on it as well? Or do I have to create a seperate S3 bucket to host my Angular application? I believe I have to use RDS for my MySql database.

Comment: You do not *have* to use RDS. Yes, you could host your Angular app off the Beanstalk instances.

Comment: are you saying I could host my angular app + node app on a single beanstalk instance? My application may have to scale in the future, so I am thinking of separating my database to a RDS service.